# How can I maintain an async CosmosDB connection pool in a FastAPI app?

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app that uses the `azure-cosmos` library to store data in a CosmosDB. I'm expecting to have a ton of traffic, so I want to create a pool of async CosmosDB clients.

Is that something the azure-cosmos library supports? I can't seem to find any examples of using a connection pool for Cosmos DB. Does it even make sense to have a pool of async CosmosDB clients? Or can one connection handle massive amounts of traffic?

If azure-cosmos has no direct support for connection pools, but it makes sense to have a pool, is there a generic library that can assist with maintaining a pool of connections?

Comment: FYI - Library and other recommendation questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

So, i think the azure-cosmos library in Python doesn't directly offer a connection pool. But  if you're expecting tons of traffic, having a pool of async CosmosDB clients can be super helpful. It's like having multiple friends ready to help instead of relying on just one hehe.

You manage these connections, making sure they're used efficiently and handling the traffic smoothly. While azure-cosmos doesn't have a built-
example of a connection pool in Python:

```html
from azure.cosmos.aio import CosmosClient

class CosmosConnectionPool:
    def __init__(self, endpoint, key):
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.key = key
        self.connections = []

    async def acquire(self):
        if not self.connections:
            connection = CosmosClient(self.endpoint, self.key)
        else:
            connection = self.connections.pop()
        return connection

    def release(self, connection):
        self.connections.append(connection)
```